# Tesseract Messing up wth digits and characters

Tags: python, tesseract

I have been using tesseract from past few months and it seems whenever there are alphanumeric it always confuses between similar looking digits and characters like 0 and O. 
But my question is the document i am using have exactly same font and pixel distribution of 0 at all places but it only confuses when its present in alphanumeric. Is there a way to stop this?
I already tried

```
api=PyTessBaseAPI(lang='eng+eng_1+eng_2+por+fra+spa') 
api.SetVariable("language_model_penalty_non_dict_word","0")
api.SetVariable("load_system_dawg","0")
api.SetVariable("language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word  ", "0");
api.SetVariable("load_freq_dawg", "0");
api.SetVariable("load_punc_dawg", "0");
api.SetVariable("load_number_dawg", "0");
```

Or any preprocessing which can help. Or may be training tesseract for this particular issue?

Here is a sample image [image]

It will confuse in "FROO11027143".
Also, at some place it also gives me confidance of 0 but it still extract the correct info?